# How to mock an environment variable that is referenced in an imported module?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have created a file containing environment variables and I am writing a test for this file. The file (`"my_variables.py"`) looks like:

```
import os

if os.getenv("VCAP_APPLICATION"):
    foo = os.getenv("foo")
else:
    foo = "bar"
```

In my test I am mocking the definition of the the `"VCAP_APPLICATION"` env var. I then assert if `my_variables.foo` is equal to `"foo"`. This is not the case, as it is equal to `"bar"`.

I think  my mocked variable is not properly mocked when importing the module. This is why I tried to import the module after mocking my variables. My test looks like this:

```
import unittest
import os
from unittest.mock import patch

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.dict(
        os.environ,
        { 
            "VCAP_APPLICATION": "True",
            "foo": "foo"
        }
    )
    def test_env_var(self):
        print(os.getenv("VCAP_APPLICATION")) # Returns True, so env var is mocked!
        import my_variables
        self.assertEqual(my_variables.foo, "foo") # Results in AssertionError
```

Asserting equality results in an AssertionError:

```
AssertionError: 'Bar' =! 'Foo'
```

I first had the import at the top of the file. I now placed it after mocking. How can I mock the env var so that my imported module uses that one?

Comment: This would be much easier if your module exposed a _function_ that returned the configuration, then you could defer execution of getenv. Otherwise it runs at import time, before the patch is applied.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the insights. i think that this is the most clean solution indeed.

Answer (score 1):

since the `os.getenv()` runs at import time unittest cant mock the object. You're going to have to get hacky by setting the environment variables in the `os` module before importing `my_variables`:

```
import unittest
import os

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_env_var(self):
        os.environ["VCAP_APPLICATION"] = "True"
        os.environ["foo"] = "foo"
        import my_variables
        self.assertEqual(my_variables.foo, "foo")
```

Comment: why would this be hacky? Is declaration (instead of mocking) in testing not done?

Comment: in my opinion its never really a good idea to edit the environ at runtime. Since you don't know if the environment variable came from the outside or from somewhere in the code. I guess it comes down to personal taste

Comment: hmm I see what you mean..

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this (still i haven't figured out how to solve the `import` statement inside `test_env_var`).

```py
import os
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        """
        For future use
        """
        super().setUpClass()

        your_envs = {
            "VCAP_APPLICATION": "True",
            "foo": "foo"
        }

        cls.env = patch.dict(in_dict=os.environ, values=your_envs, clear=True)
        cls.env.start()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        """
        For future use
        """
        super().tearDownClass()
        cls.env.stop()

    def test_env_var(self):
        print(os.getenv("VCAP_APPLICATION"))  # Returns True, so env var is mocked!
        import my_variables
        self.assertEqual(my_variables.foo, "foo")  # Results in AssertionError


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```